# Is there a way to split items in a stack in Torchlight 2

Tags: torchlight-2

Has anyone found one?

Lets say I have a stack of 10 health potions and want to sell 3. Can I do it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes there is - you can split a stack of items by holding down the <kbd>CONTROL</kbd> key and clicking on the stack.

[image]

This will pop up a little window that allows you to select how many you want to split off into a new stack.